# Neural Network is pretty bad

Tags: java, debugging, machine-learning, neural-network, refactoring

I created a neural network today that learned the XOR operator, and it worked like a charm.
Then I refactored it (without saving an image, duh) and it didn't work anymore.

Now it works again, but it is pretty bad:

```
Learing...
749142 out of 1000000 training samples were correct (74.9142%)
Testing...
756 out of 1000 testing samples were correct (75.6%)
```

Earlier this day, it would always have a 100.0% success in the testing phase...
I tried it with different amounts of hidden layers or neurons in the hidden layers, I cannot get it back to these awesome results. After 1000000 training iterations it should easily have 100.0% right?

this is my training method:

```
    public void train() {
        float delta = (float) ((1.0 - output)*(1.0+output) * error * NNetwork.LEARING_RATE);
        for(NConnection n : inputs) {
            n.getInputNeuron().error += n.getWeight() * error;
            n.setWeight(n.getWeight() + n.output() * delta);
        }
        error = 0;
    }
```

set error:

```
public float setError(float desired) {
        error = desired - output;
        return error;
}
```

output calculation:

```
public float calcOutput() {
        if(isInputNeuron) {
            return valueIfInputNeuron;
        } else {
            float input_sum = 0.0f;
            for(NConnection n : inputs) {
                input_sum += n.input() * n.getWeight();
            }
            output = lookupSigmoid(input_sum); 
            return output;
        }
}
```

All of the above methods are inside the Neuron class.
This is the method the Network class uses to train itself:

```
/**
     * Trains the net by giving the correct desired result to it
     * The network will then calculate its error and try to improve
     * @param correctResult the correct desired result
     * @return whether the average error per output neuron is below the acceptable error or not
     */
    public boolean train(float correctResult) {
        float totalOutputError = 0.0f;
        for(int i = 0; i < output_layer.length; i++) {
            totalOutputError += output_layer[i].setError(correctResult);
            output_layer[i].train();
        }
        for (int i = hidden_layers.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {     
            for (int j = 0; j < hidden_layers[i].length; j++) {
                  hidden_layers[i][j].train();
            }
        }
        if(Math.abs(totalOutputError / output_layer.length) < ACCEPTABLE_ERROR) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone see a bug in here?
Maybe my sigmoid function is unfit?
I can post more code if you need it...

(By the way, when the Network achieved 100.0%, it hat 2 input neurons, 2 hidden ones and one output neuron)

Comment: perhaps learning about how to use GIT or SVN locally will be beneficial to you, to help avoid this problem in the future

Comment: Yep, usually I do keep images but this time I didn't... For no particular reason... I will never forget about doing that again -.-

Comment: Training a million times with only 2 input, 2 hidden, and 1 output seems to be over training. But I am no neural network expert.

Comment: Well, the result doesn't become better with less trainings. And since my training data is random, it should not be a problem should it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the network was not working properly before, and now it is. The website I used to learn about neural nets said that 75% is a decent result for a network like mine considering its simplicity.